# Simple Prepared Statement Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I am trying to return some data from my localhost MySQL database, following example 1 [on this page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php).

The database and table both exist, when I run the query using PhpMyAdmin I get 5 results returned successfully.

My page is called **test.php**, whenever I visit the page all I can see is the word '*connected*'.

My code is as follows;

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database'); 
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');
} else {
    echo "connected </br>";
}

/* prepare statement */
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Status FROM hostloadslog LIMIT 5")) {
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind variables to prepared statement */
    $stmt->bind_result($col1);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf("%s %s\n", $col1);
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: check for Errors after prepare

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot put the prepare statement inside of an if statement. You can put the execute in an if statement though.

Comment: Look at what `$col1` looks like, too: `printf("%s %s\n", $col1);` is wrong in several ways: there's 2 placeholders, but only 1 value is passed, and `$col1` isn't a string as you seem to think it is

Comment: @Robert nope it is possible to do that as per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: Ah, I know in pdo I couldn't do that, so I made an assumption it was the same in mysqli.

Comment: You were right @EliasVanOotegem as soon as I removed one of the `%s` it worked! Strange that I didn't receive any error though - is this normal? Could I add in error reporting? Also, add an answer and I'll gladly accept - thanks!

Comment: Instead of `printf("%s %s\n", $col1);` just use `echo $col1`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and apply that to your query. You may just get something back. and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Robert why wouldn't you be able? oO It's ugly, but it should be valid nonetheless.

Comment: It through a fatal error. I will mess around with it later tonight. I am at school now.

Comment: @johnny_s: posted a quick answer about the `printf` error, and recommended development ini settings (strict error reporting and display_errors)

Comment: @johnny_s NP, don't know why you got down-voted, I'll up-vote to counter though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, the problem was the use of `printf`:

```
printf("%s %s\n", $col1);
```

fails, because you're using 2 placeholders, but only ever passing a single string. Change it to either

```
echo $col1 . PHP_EOL;
//or
printf("%s\n", $col1);
```

To debug code like this more easily, you can set both `error_reporting` to -1 (or in the ini file to `E_STRICT|E_ALL`), and set `display_errors` to `on`.